# Is hook_boot() removed from drupal 8?

Tags: 8, hooks

Is [`hook_boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7.x) hook removed from drupal 8?

If yes then what is alternative method which can be used instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1909596)

> In Drupal 8 hook_boot() was removed since the same results can be
>   achieved with other ways, for example:
>
> - A module that needs to interrupt the request very early based on certain conditions can use an event listener (see #1794754: Convert
>     ban_boot() to an event listener) (Note that modules are loaded by this
>     stage unlike in Drupal 7.)
> - A module that needs to run on cached pages should prompt its users to add code in settings.php

Comment: or you can use  a middle ware, as commented there.